# React-Native: Handle Change of Input with state

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to change the value of input inside of a modal by handleChange and put it inside of this.state.value. Unfortunately all I get while debugging the handleChange function is: value = undefined (there's no "value" in event.target!)

```
export default class AddPlanningView extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        items: [],
        value: "",
        amount: 0,
        unit: ""};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        value: event.target.value,
        amount: event.target.amount,
        unit: event.target.unit
    });
}

openModal() {
    this.refs.modal.open()
}

closeModal() {
    this.refs.modal.close()
}

addItem() {
    //Validate Item
    this.closeModal();
}

render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Header>
                ...
            </Header>
            <Content>
                ...
                <Modal
                    backdrop={false}
                    ref={"modal"}
                    swipeToClose={true}>
                    <View style={styles.modalView}>
                        <ListItem>
                            <InputGroup>
                                <Icon name="ios-clipboard" style={{ color: '#0A69FE' }}/>
                                <Input type="text" inlineLabel label="Item" placeholder="Item" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                            </InputGroup>
                        </ListItem>
                        ...
                        <Button block onPress={this.addItem.bind(this)}>
                            <Icon name='save' theme={IconTheme}/>
                        </Button>
                    </View>
                </Modal>
            </Content>
            <Footer>
                <FooterTab>
                    <Button transparent onPress={this.openModal.bind(this)}>
                        <Icon name='md-add'  color="#000"/>
                        New Item
                    </Button>
                </FooterTab>
            </Footer>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why?

Thanks

Dave

Comment: No need for binding the handleChange

Answer (score 2):

acording to React Native [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input), you should use `onChangeText` instead of `onChange` for handle change in a Component:

```
<customComponent onChangeText={this.handleChange}/>
```

now in `handleChange` handler function:

```
handleChange = (textValue)=>{
    this.setState({value: textValue})
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You are binding `handleChange` to `this` two times.
First in constructor `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);`.
Then you declare `handleChange` as arrow function which will also bind the function to `this`.

```
handleChange = (event) => {
  // stuff
}
```

The solution is to

- Remove binding from constructor (recommend)
- or
- Declare `handleChange` without fat arrow syntax

I would recommend you to read Handling events (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html) as homework :)

Comment: He is not acking for react but react native